# Cannot remove incorrectly created Hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

While working with Hive I accidentally submitted a CREATE TABLE as follows:

```
hive> create external table hivetable(hiveid INT, hivename string) location '/';
```

The table created and now I can't remove it - if I select * from the table I get a huge output of gibberish data - for example:

```
NULL    �rg.4ӣ�7�-�j��>�9Wϙ�U�m�eO�0���Un=7=W
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
NULL    �s�2�+�q��GVZ�ur�*Y�M�s���G��R0
NULL    c��ㇷ'o~8����e]�ay>ѫjCE5
NULL    �S�&�M�I��S���"��p�
NULL    NULL
NULL    G2I|=i
NULL    �Q?y����:R�T���QA6X�A+pI}�C?\��0Ek[�h�v�6�G�onය��^�;s4��
NULL    �Og�oߟ���d|'���h�j7!��E;�o��    ���G���\�\��p��tm��Gwx��e����c�
                                                                       nñ*8�����U�&|���B��ց�6��%��Ŵ⮶��)H�obN�3�?ܵ�$N�T��$2��p�$�f��hU��ڶ��Lg�!԰x)۔2/���RҭN�D����L�[��ٻ��˳�Ň���<roi�W������jB���ס1L0&���g��0�}��TV`c�.����Q�9n���*�D ����r"~0]5�
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
NULL    ����_u�:g1^��}T�U�'����
                               ����b���Ӳ�U9�fC�1�nI��H��
                                                        ����(
```

I'm thinking I've created a table which tried to read the entire HDFS filesystem directory structure - however I can't locate the table in HDFS, and although I can see the table in the default hive tables, I can't drop the table. As of right now I haven't noticed any impact, but I'd like to remove the table record and ensure everything in cleaned up. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Arthur

EDIT:

Error when trying to drop table:

```
    > drop table hivetable;
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:java.lang.NullPointerException)
hive>
```

I've since worsened the situation:

```
hive> LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/root/arthurs_stuff/empty.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE hivetable;
Loading data to table default.hivetable
Moved: 'hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/app-logs' to trash at: hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/user/root/.Trash/Current
Moved: 'hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/apps' to trash at: hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/user/root/.Trash/Current
Moved: 'hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/ats' to trash at: hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/user/root/.Trash/Current
Moved: 'hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/demo' to trash at: hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/user/root/.Trash/Current
Moved: 'hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/flume' to trash at: hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/user/root/.Trash/Current
Moved: 'hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/hdp' to trash at: hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/user/root/.Trash/Current
Moved: 'hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/mapred' to trash at: hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/user/root/.Trash/Current
Moved: 'hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/mr-history' to trash at: hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/user/root/.Trash/Current
Moved: 'hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/ranger' to trash at: hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/user/root/.Trash/Current
Moved: 'hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/root' to trash at: hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/user/root/.Trash/Current
Moved: 'hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/spark-history' to trash at: hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/user/root/.Trash/Current
Moved: 'hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/tmp' to trash at: hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/user/root/.Trash/Current
Table default.hivetable stats: [numFiles=856, numRows=0, totalSize=574803295, rawDataSize=0]
OK
```

followed by:

```
hadoop fs -mv /user/root/.Trash/Current/* /
```

Fortunately this is just a sandbox VM for study :)

Perhaps I should just look at reformatting HDFS or something?

Comment: @BenWatson see edits

Comment: i would try to invalidate the metadata of the table then try to drop it again. "invalidate metadata yourTableName"